# How do I take a part from terminal output?

Tags: shell

If I run a program then it will shows following on the terminal screen

```
Total Events Processed                                  799992
Events Aborted (part of RBs)                                 0
Events Rolled Back                                           0
Efficiency                                              100.00 %
Total Remote (shared mem) Events Processed                   0
Percent Remote Events                                     0.00 %
Total Remote (network) Events Processed                      0
Percent Remote Events                                     0.00 %

Total Roll Backs                                             0
Primary Roll Backs                                           0
Secondary Roll Backs                                         0
Fossil Collect Attempts                                      0
Total GVT Computations                                       0

Net Events Processed                                    799992
Event Rate (events/sec)                              3987042.0
```

If I want to take first and fifth row from the output then how do I do that?

Comment: Edit your tags to indicate if you are using Linux/Unix or Windows OR ?? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `grep` utility if it is available:

```
$ ./program | grep 'Total Events Processed\|Total Remote (shared mem) Events Processed'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think sed would do this, e.g.:

```
sed -n -e 1p -e 5p input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with awk, too:

```
awk 'NR==1 || NR==5 {print;} NR==6 {nextfile;}'
```

Or in prettier sed:

```
sed -ne '1p;5p;6q'
```

Or even by piping through a pure Bourne shell script, if that's the way you roll (per your tag):

```
#!/bin/sh
n=0
while read line; do
  n=$((n+1))
  if [ $n = 1 -o $n = 5 ]; then
    echo "$line"
  elif [ $n = 6 ]; then
    break
  fi
done
```

Note that in all cases we're quitting at record 6, because there's no need to continue walking through the output.